# php скрипт который будет запускаться из консоли

Tags: php

Решать за меня не надо, просто подскажите в какую сторону двигаться, или к примеру просто порядок действий( а разбираться буду сам) за ранее благодарен за понимание, я в этом деле пока что новенький!

Напишите php скрипт который будет запускаться из консоли. 
Команда php нашскрипт.php [http://где.то/там/](http://%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5.%D1%82%D0%BE/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC/) выводит все ссылки (href атрибуты тега ), которые есть на странице [http://где.то/там/](http://%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5.%D1%82%D0%BE/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC/). 
Url должны преобразовываться к абсолютной форме, дубликатов быть не должно.

Comment: вот и смысл минусовать ??? попросил просто подсказать, если не нравится данный вопрос внеси корректировки, либо подскажи, либо выйди вообще...

Comment: напиши обычный скрипт, а потом просто запусти его в консоли.... проблема не ясна. ты не можешь написать скрипт или запускать из консоли?

Comment: я не могу понять с чего начать, возможно есть примеру какие-то, что бы  смогу под себя реализовать

Comment: так примеры чего тебе нужны? как запустить скрипт из консоли или как обратиться к сайту и взять ссылки? если второе - это надо почитать про cURL к примеру или простой file_get_contents в связке с Simple HTML DOM Parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Задача запускать с виндовс или линукс?

Comment: запуск на виндовс

Answer (score 2):

- загрузить страницу
- пройтись по всему DOM
- найти узлы a (ну или если совсем "в лоб", то регуляркой искать элементы вида `<a href`)
- прочитать у каждого такого узла содержимое атрибута href - это и будет ссылка
- привести ссылки к абсолютному виду (если ссылка не содержит http, а
  начинается с / или вообще имени файла, то добавить либо только домен,
  либо домен и путь до текущего каталога)

P.S. учитывайте, что если задача не синтетическая, а реальная (или если автор с "юморком"), то `a href` могут быть не всеми ссылками. Между ними могут быть другие атрибуты. Что-нибудь типа `a class="menu" href`.

P.P.S. Для парсинга html, помимо упомянутой библиотеки Simple HTML DOM и регулярок есть варианты с XPath и DOM, phpQuery и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('http://ru.stackoverflow.com/');

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) //Находим все линки
    echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

сделал таким образом, что скажете ? Url должны преобразовываться к абсолютной форме, дубликатов быть не должно.- Как понять ? то есть абсолютная форма это mySite/rrr; mySite/www; а не /rrr; /www?

Comment: да http://site.ru/folder/index.html - абсолютная форма. /folder/index.html и просто index.html - относительные. Если начинается со слеша, значит от корня сайта. Если слеша нет, то от текущего адреса (например, другая страница в текущем каталоге). Ещё теоретически может быть адрес вида ../folder2/index.html, это тоже относительный. Только вы сперва спускаетесь к корню от текущего на 1 уровень, а потом уже смотрите адрес.