# запуск скрипта в консоле

Tags: php, cmd

Создал скрипт который парсит все ссылки сайта, когда запускаю его в браузере, все работает,а через консоль выдает ошибку. В чем может быть проблема? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

    $html = file_get_contents('https://sinoptik.ua/');
    $html =str_get_html($html);

    foreach($html->find('a') as $element) //Находим все линки
    echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: Скорее всего у Вас ничего не пришло в html. Думаю перед тем как делать цикл с find Вам нужно проверить на `!empty($html)`

Comment: И добавьте **к этому вопросу** код где он [падает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/693110/183125). А не в ответе предыдущего

Comment: падает на строке с циклом

Comment: Перед циклом `if(!empty($html)) { цикл }`

Comment: не помогло, может проблема с конфигурацией php.ini?

Comment: а что в $html приходит? объект?

Comment: $html = file_get_contents('https://sinoptik.ua/');
    $html = str_get_html($html);

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62346/discussion-between-konstantin-okhotnick-and-).